# If and SORT Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good Morning,

I need a formula where it counts the top 3 based on "Eindscore" in column L but only from the "Categorie" found in F.

So I think a combination of Query, Sort and If would work but I am open to any ideas.

The Category is ever so changing; While now F27 is Color, it could be something else, so that should be taken into account as well.

Example worksheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IXadg9azc1piL72QvHHITrkObXVroBHAZ8g33fSDVEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Share a sample workbook and show your desired output.

Comment: @Harun24hr There you go [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IXadg9azc1piL72QvHHITrkObXVroBHAZ8g33fSDVEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: is Category always a B column?

Comment: Yes indeed @player0

Comment: Why not using a pivot table (with adding one colum in the database the desired categories)

Answer (score 1):

After defining a ranking in the dataset for each entry, filtered by catergory.

```
=MATCH(C2,QUERY(A$2:C,"select C where B = '"&B2&"' order by C desc"),0)
```

[image]

You can use the data and show the top 3 with a pivot table.

```
=QUERY(A$2:D,"select D, max(A) where A is not null and D <= 3 group by D pivot B")
```

[image]

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kMX1F05qw-UGg-diNSxpyW7fNeGu6qpuQNOjr8h9fTE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Neat. I have taken the liberty of using your idea in my answer.

Comment: Great this is amazing @W.S.  The only thing left in this formula is that I would need the numbers in some cases as well and a formula where I can take the top X from a certain Category, for instance "Color" and paste it somewhere else, while it still being dynamic

Comment: I also have the problem where if pos 3 has 3 colors for instances, it only shows one. Can we show 1 Black, 2 Yellow, 3 Brown, 3 Orange, 3 Green ?

Comment: What about this? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3S64JmAqoxlASC4h5tqs6ialCZPZG-BZKha_JwJQew/copy I used an extra helper column. There are probably some ways to get rid of the helper column and include it all in the query formula.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a query should do it

```
=query($A1:$C11,"select A where B='"&B15&"' order by C desc  limit 3 label A ''",1)
```

in B16 and copy across to E16 and H16.

[image]

**EDIT**

So borrowing heavily from @W.S. , you could do a general formula like:

```
ArrayFormula(query({A2:C,countifs(B2:B,B2:B,C2:C,">="&C2:C)},"select max(Col1) where Col4<=3  and Col1 is not null group by Col4 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks so far!

The problem is that we work with different variables, scraped from a website. So we never know what the category might be. While B2 till B6 now can be Color, for another product it could be Voltage for B2 till B4 and then B5 Material and B6 Function

Comment: So there might be more (or less) than three categories of interest and you want to do the top three of each of them?

Comment: Essentially, we are scraping data, 1 to 15 categories. Then we choose which ones we deem most interesting, so this could in theory be up to 15 categories.

And indeed I want to do a top 3 of each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Can try `SORTN()` like-

```
=SORTN(FILTER(C2:C11,B2:B11="Color"),3,,1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that we work with different variables, scraped from a website. So we never know what the category might be. 

Also the characteristic itself needs to be listed